# Using Large Function in Excel with or Conditionals on Array Function

Tags: arrays, excel

I am trying to get the second largest value of column C if column A is either "Text 1" or "Text 2". It seem to keep returning an error. I have tried:

```
{=large((if(A:A="Text 1",C:C),if(A:A="Text 2",C:C)),2)}
```

And

```
{=large(if(or(A:A="Text 1",A:A="Text 2"),C:C),2)}
```

No success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Got it to work with regexmatch ie  {=large(if(regexmatch(A:A, "Text 1|Text 2"),C:C),2)}

Comment: regexmatch?????

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try and stay away from arrays as much as I can for efficiency reasons. Here is an example of a non-array formulae you can use to find what you need:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(MaxRange)*(CriteriaRange=Criteria),2)
```

Where:

```
14 = Large, to find the maximum value
6 = Ignore error values - makes only the criteria values applicable
MaxRange = The range of values you want to pull the 2nd largest from
CriteriaRange = The criteria range you want to evaluate
Criteria = The criteria you want to match in the above range
2 = Specifies the 2nd largest: 1 would be largest etc
```

If you haven't noticed this follows the same principles of a `=SUMPRODUCT`. So to deal with multiple `AND` criteria you can multiply them together i.e:

```
(MaxRange)*(CriteriaRange1=Criteria1)*(CriteriaRange2=Criteria2)
```

And to do an `OR` condition you add them together:

```
(MaxRange)*((CriteriaRange1=Criteria1)+(CriteriaRange2=Criteria2))
```

This results in the formula for you being:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(C:C)*((A:A="Text 1")+(A:A="Text 2")),2)
```